# Radix sort with benchmarks

Tags: c, benchmarking, radix-sort

I am trying to time [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) on 128 bit unsigned integers for different base sizes (that I call bitwidth).  My code has at least the following problems:

- The radix sort itself may run slower than it would otherwise as the bit
  width, number of passes etc are not constants that the compiler can
  understand and also maybe the use of variable length arrays.
- I use variable length arrays. It might be better without those
- It doesn't work (crashes due to stack overflow) for bitwidth > 18.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>


#define LENGTH 1000000

void print128(__uint128_t u) {
  if (u>9) print128(u/10);
  putchar(48+(int)(u%10));
}


// 2^(bitwidth) == count_size for counting sort. 16 is 128/bitwidth == num_passes (number of radix sort passes)
typedef __uint128_t u128;
typedef uint32_t u32;
u128* radix_sort128(u128* array, u32 size, u32 count_size, u32 num_passes, u32 bitwidth) {
  u32 counts[num_passes][count_size];
  memset(&counts, 0, count_size * num_passes * sizeof(u32));
  u128* cpy = (u128*) malloc(size * sizeof(u128));
  u32 o[num_passes];
  memset(o, 0, sizeof o);
  // u32 o[num_passes] = {0};
  u32 t, x, pos;
  u128* array_from, * array_to;
  for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    for (pos = 0; pos < num_passes; pos++) {
      t = (array[x] >> bitwidth * pos) % count_size;
      counts[pos][t]++;
    }
  }
  for (x = 0; x < count_size; x++) {
    for (pos = 0; pos < num_passes; pos++) {
      t = o[pos] + counts[pos][x];
      counts[pos][x] = o[pos];
      o[pos] = t;
    }
  }
  for (pos = 0; pos < num_passes; pos++) {
    array_from = pos % 2 == 0 ? array : cpy;
    array_to = pos % 2 == 0 ? cpy : array;
    for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      t = (array_from[x] >> bitwidth * pos) & 0xff;
      array_to[counts[pos][t]] = array_from[x];
      counts[pos][t]++;
    }
  }
  free(cpy);
  return array;
}

uint64_t wyhash64_x;


uint64_t wyhash64() {
  wyhash64_x += 0x60bee2bee120fc15;
  __uint128_t tmp;
  tmp = (__uint128_t) wyhash64_x * 0xa3b195354a39b70d;
  uint64_t m1 = (tmp >> 64) ^ tmp;
  tmp = (__uint128_t)m1 * 0x1b03738712fad5c9;
  uint64_t m2 = (tmp >> 64) ^ tmp;
  return m2;
}


int main() {
  u128* vals128 = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(*vals128));
  u128 lower;
  u128 higher;
  struct timespec start, end;

  // make an array of random u128s 
  for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    lower = (u128) wyhash64();
    higher = (u128) wyhash64();
    higher = higher << 64;
    vals128[i] = lower + higher;
  }
  for (u32 bitwidth = 8; bitwidth < 20; bitwidth+=2){
    u32 num_passes = 128/bitwidth;
    u32 count_size = 1 << bitwidth;
    printf("bitwidth %d num_passes %d count_size %d\n", bitwidth, num_passes, count_size);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    radix_sort128(vals128, LENGTH, count_size, num_passes, bitwidth);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    printf("%f seconds\n", (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0);
  }
  free(vals128);
}
```

Any improvements gratefully received.

**Edit**

Corrected bug.  `& 0xff` is now `% count_size`.

Comment: The problem is the 0xff. That needs fixing

Comment: Hi, you can refer to this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/216460/190450. The code is in c++. But you can go through it as a reference.

Comment: num_passes is wrong unless 128 is divisible by bitwidth. You need to round up.

Answer (score 5):

There's an opaque magic number here, that reduces portability:

> ```
>   putchar(48+(int)(u%10));
> ```

I think that was intended to be `'0'`, and we unnecessarily created an ASCII-only program.

This function might be better if it works in larger chunks, and recursed less:

```
void print128(__uint128_t u) {
    static const uint64_t ten18 = 10000000000000000000u;
    if (u < ten18) {
        printf("%" PRIu64, (uint64_t)u);
    } else {
        print128(u/ten18);
        printf("%018" PRIu64, (uint64_t)(u % ten18));
    }
}
```

---

> ```
>   u128* cpy = (u128*) malloc(size * sizeof(u128));
> ```

Don't cast the return from `malloc()` - it's a `void*`, which is convertible to any pointer type in C.  And it's good practice to refer the size directly to the variable being initialised, rather than to its type - that makes it easier for the reader to see correctness without having to find the declaration, which may be further away.  Another good habit is to multiply beginning with the `size_t` quantity, which can avoid overflow when there are more terms in the product.

```
   u128* cpy = malloc(sizeof *cpy * size);
```

Whatever we do, we **must not** dereference that pointer until we know it's not a null pointer.

```
   if (!cpy) {
       return NULL;
   }
```

---

> ```
> uint64_t wyhash64()
> ```

This function declaration should be a prototype (as should `main()`):

```
uint64_t wyhash64(void)
```

There's no need for `wyhash64_x` to have global scope - it would be better as a `static` local within the function.

Comment: On linux at least, I am not sure malloc ever returns NULL . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674370/why-does-malloc-or-new-never-return-null

Comment: It certainly does when you hit your `ulimit -v` value.

Comment: That is true.  It looks like the code as written is actually incorrect because of the 0xFF. Would you be able to add a correction to your great answer?  That is it doesn't work for bitwidth other than 8.  I think the mask just has to be change to count-size - 1 .

Comment: It's probably better for you to add an answer of your own to explain that (and will help you build reputation here).  (We like having multiple different answers here on Code Review.)

Comment: As I mention in a comment above, there seems to be a fatal bug in any case

Comment: @TobySpeight OK, LSNED.  I suspect my C++ side of the brain had confused my C side.

Comment: Yes, one of the ways in which C++ isn't "just like C".

Answer (score 2):

Not much left after @Toby Speight review.

**Bug?**

Code has a mysterious `& 0xff`.  Perhaps `% count_size`?

```
u32 counts[num_passes][count_size];
...
// t = (array[x] >> bitwidth * pos) & 0xff;
t = (array[x] >> bitwidth * pos) % count_size;
counts[pos][t]++;
```

**Minor bug**

Assuming `int` is 32-bit`.

When `int` is 16-bit, `1 << bitwidth` shifts outside `int` range.

```
// u32 count_size = 1 << bitwidth;
u32 count_size = ((u32)1) << bitwidth; // or the like.
```

`for` loop like-wise fails.  As `i` is used to index arrays, recommend `size_t`.

```
#define LENGTH 1000000
// for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) { 
for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
```

**Multiplication order for size**

Rather than assume 32-bit for `size_t`, (e.g. it may be 64-bit), perform the size multiplication starting with `size_t` to take advantage where a wide `size_t` may prevent overflow of `u32 * u32`.  (I now see Toby mentioned part of this.)

```
... u32 count_size, u32 num_passes ...
// u32 counts[num_passes][count_size];
// memset(&counts, 0, count_size * num_passes * sizeof(u32));
//                    ^---------------------^ may overflow 32 bit math  
memset(&counts, 0, sizeof(u32) * count_size * num_passes);
                   ^----------------------^ Math done using wider of size_t, u32
```

Even simpler, just use the size of the array.

```
// memset(&counts, 0, count_size * num_passes * sizeof(u32));
memset(&counts, 0, sizeof counts);
```

**`u32` vs `uint32_t`**

Rather than a user/implementation defined fixed width type, consider using the standard one.

To know if `u32` code is correct obliges a look-up of `u32` definition.

**Superfluous casts**

Not needed with up conversions.

```
//lower = (u128) wyhash64();
// higher = (u128) wyhash64();
lower = wyhash64();
higher = wyhash64();
```

Comment: And If you do both `malloc()` and `memset()`, use `calloc()` instead, and you don't have to worry about those sizes.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Sounds like a good idea, perhaps post that, even if it is only a small review.

Comment: Will % count_size be as fast as & (count_size - 1)?

Comment: Can you also see how to fix “ It doesn't work (crashes due to stack overflow) for bitwidth > 18.”?

Comment: There is another bug it seems. I don't think num_passes is correct if 128 is not divisible by bitwidth,

Comment: @Anush "Will % count_size be as fast as & (count_size - 1)?" --> maybe the same, maybe slower, maybe different on your machine vs mine.   [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: @Anush "I don't think num_passes is correct if 128 is not divisible by bitwidth" --> Likely true.  Rather than worry about [small performance issues](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/265593/radix-sort-with-benchmarks/265612?noredirect=1#comment524658_265612), make functionally correct for  lots of different inputs.

Comment: @Anush  "It doesn't work (crashes due to stack overflow) for bitwidth > 18" --> `for (u32 bitwidth = 8; bitwidth < 20; bitwidth+=2){` is a first place to look as code has an artifical limit here.  `bitwidth` , once reaching more than 18, exits the loops and calls `free()`.  I think your "It" in "It doesn't work" is referring to some other unposted variation on this code.